# Trim leading numbers from string up to a delimeter

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to strip leading numbers in PHP up to the delimeter "_"
Examples:
(input on the left, desired output on the right)

```
1_abc.jpg -> abc.jpg
01_abc.jpg -> abc.jpg
100_abc.jpg -> abc.jpg
100_12abc.jpg -> 12abc.jpg
12abc.jpg -> 12abc.jpg
```

Thanks in advance. I'm really bad at regex.

Comment: http://www.regexr.com will help you.

Comment: If you're really bad at regex, you have two options available before asking others to write them for you: (1) Learn how to use them or (2) solve the problem without regex. Both will mean that you can support and maintain your code.

Comment: same thing can be done by expload

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site that people write code for you, please use google and at least attempt to get working code before asking on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need regex?

```
$pos = strpos($string, '_');

if($pos !== false)
  $string = substr($string, $pos + 1);
```

...or:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^\d+_/', '', $string);
```

(`^` matches the start of the string and `d+` matches numbers)

Comment: your preg_replace won't work for the 12abc.jpg - need the "?" after the underscore.

Comment: Read the Q: `12abc.jpg -> 12abc.jpg`

Comment: yeah, i see. you are right

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.
$string = preg_replace('/^\d+_/', '', $string);